# Can we use the concept of inheritance in Django rest framework in ModelViewSets?

Tags: django, python-2.7, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I'm repeating my code, again and again, in different `ModelViewSets` and the only thing that is changing here is the Model's name. So, I want to write a base class for this and send each model's name as an argument, but its not working.

Any help?

```
class RemitterQueryViewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RemitterQueryView.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RemitterQueryViewSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_base_path(self):
        splitted_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri().split('?')
        base_url = splitted_url[0]
        return base_url

    def get_queryset(self):
        limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit', 26)
        offset = self.request.query_params.get('offset', 0)
        filter_list = self.request.query_params.get('filter_list', None)
        sort_list = self.request.query_params.get('sort_list', None)
        if filter_list is None and sort_list is None:
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset))[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is not None and sort_list is not None:
            filter_columns = self.get_filter_list()
            sort_columns = self.get_sort_list()
            sort_columns = list(itertools.chain(*sort_columns))
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns).order_by(*sort_columns)[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is None and sort_list is not None:
            sort_columns = self.get_sort_list()
            sort_columns = list(itertools.chain(*sort_columns))
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset)).order_by(*sort_columns)[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is not None and sort_list is None:
            filter_columns = self.get_filter_list()
            # print(filter_columns)
            # print(MockData.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns)[0:int(limit)])
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns)[0:int(limit)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common mixin class and inherit this mixin in all CBV.

```
class MixinView:

    def get_base_path(self):
        splitted_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri().split('?')
        base_url = splitted_url[0]
        return base_url

    def get_queryset(self):
        limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit', 26)
        offset = self.request.query_params.get('offset', 0)
        filter_list = self.request.query_params.get('filter_list', None)
        sort_list = self.request.query_params.get('sort_list', None)
        if filter_list is None and sort_list is None:
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset))[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is not None and sort_list is not None:
            filter_columns = self.get_filter_list()
            sort_columns = self.get_sort_list()
            sort_columns = list(itertools.chain(*sort_columns))
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns).order_by(*sort_columns)[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is None and sort_list is not None:
            sort_columns = self.get_sort_list()
            sort_columns = list(itertools.chain(*sort_columns))
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset)).order_by(*sort_columns)[0:int(limit)]

        elif filter_list is not None and sort_list is None:
            filter_columns = self.get_filter_list()
            # print(filter_columns)
            # print(MockData.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns)[0:int(limit)])
            return RemitterQueryView.objects.filter(id__gt=int(offset), **filter_columns)[0:int(limit)]


class RemitterQueryViewViewset(MixinView, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RemitterQueryView.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RemitterQueryViewSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

Here your get_queryset method from MixinView will get executed.